# How to change crashHub port in Springboot

Tags: spring, crash, spring-boot

I am using Springboot in my project, i start an embedded Springboot application inside my App. My app is already having a crashHub which is conflicting with springBoot's crashHub, so how i can change the springBoot's crashHub port, I don't want to do it through a XML File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [extensive list of configuration properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) in Spring Boot's documentation, including those for configuring the ports used by the remote shell: `shell.ssh.port` and `shell.telnet.port`.

You should configure one or both of these properties in your `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Can i do this in a Configuration java file? i don't want to add an extra application.properties file just for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can do it by specifying parameter to java:

```
-Dshell.ssh.port=<your-port>
```

Or command line argument for you application:

```
--shell.ssh.port=<your-port>
```